# Error npm installing consensys diligence takehome bignumber util

Tags: truffle, command-line

````
```
/sudo npm install
Password:
Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git /Users/quantum/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f59a30ef
/Users/quantum/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f59a30ef/.git: Permission denied

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:291:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:599:12)
```
````

Why is this failing? I reinstalled node and git.

It now is stuck on 
Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git /Users/quantum/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f59a30ef
/Users/quantum/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f59a30ef/.git: Permission denied

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:291:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:599:12)
```

⸨            ░░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:npm: sill extract caller-path@0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your npm cache is messed up.

Try `npm cache clean --force` and reinstalling dependencies.

Comment: I completely removed npm and node before trying this, I'll try this command now